# Python - append specific files from the same folder to one *.csv

Tags: python

I am having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to append all logs in csv format from one folder to one csv file. My idividual files are named new+date_time. Something like **new01-10-2020_1440** and all are stored in the same folder. The new component always stays.

I tried below loops with no luck. What I am doing wrong.

```
import glob

with open('path to main file V.csv', 'a') as singleFile:
    for csv in glob('*.csv'):
        if csv == 'new.csv':
            pass
        else:
            for line in open(csv, 'r'):
                singleFile.write(line)
```

or

```
import os

def read_folder('path to folder')
    files = os.listdir('path to folder')
    df = []
    for f in files:
        print(f)
        csv_file = csv_folder + "/" + f
        df.append(pd.read_csv(csv_file))
        df_full = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
        return df, full
```

Comment: Hi, you files have the headers? You want to skip all of them, append all or just append the first and skip the others? Can you share and example of one file?

Comment: skip headers and just append data from each file.

Comment: Please [edit] to show 1) sample input files (main file, files from target folder) 2) current output that you get and if there are error messages, post that too. It's not clear what exactly is wrong.

Comment: As a side note, don't use `csv` as a variable name, because there is a built-in `csv` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import glob

list_csv = glob.glob('new*.csv')   # List all the files in the folder

with open('final_file.csv', 'a') as singleFile:   # Open the file in append mode
    for csvPath in list_csv:    # For each found file
        with open(csvPath, 'r') as readFile:    # Open the found file in read mode 
            #Skip the header row
            readFile.__next__()     # This work on python 3, for python 2 use readFile.next()
            # Write to file
            for line in readFile:
                singleFile.write(f'{line}\n')   # On python 2 singleFile.write(line + '\n')
```

To take the file you have to use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html#glob.glob) not just `glob()`, this is valid for your current import, if you want do just `glob()` change your `import glob` as `from glob import glob`.

You said that your filename format is `new01-10-2020_1440.csv` so take all the files that have the name like this `new*.csv` and rename your output file with a unique name like `final_file.csv`, so you can avoid to use a specific if to skip the created file because you get all the files that starts with `new`. **Note** that the `*` means that after `new` you can have any char, but the file extension must be `.csv`.

To skip the first row, that is the header row I suppose, on python 3.x you can use [`.__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) on python 2.x [`.next()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next).

Answer (score -2):

You can try with `concat` with parameter `axis=1` if you need append vertically:

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(Q, header=None) for Q in csv_list ], axis=1)
```

If you want to append horizontally is default parameter `axis=0`(which can be omit by you):

```
import pandas as pd
combined_csv = pd.concat([ pd.read_csv(Q, header=None) for Q in csv_list ], ignore_index=True)
```